# In html table how to show Yes/No instead of 1/0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am receiving a json file from server and in this file there are some values 0/1. And therse values are showing same in html table. But i want to show these values as Yes/No.How can i do that

I am sharing my code

```
$.getJSON('list.php', function(data) {
 $.each(data.classlists , function(i, f) {

         var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Info" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.messageName + "</td>" + "</tr>" +"<tr>" + "<td>" + "Link" + "</td>" +"<td><a target='_blank' href='"+link+"'>"+"Get INFO"+"</a></td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Teacher" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.date + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Is Live Now" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.liveClassStatus + "</td>" + "</tr>"  ;
```

in front of Is Live Now i want to show Yes or No

Pleaee make some necessary change

Comment: `(f.liveClassStatus ? "Yes" : "No")`

Comment: You also don't need so much string concatenation: `"<tr><td>Info</td><td>" + f.messageName + "</td>...` etc

Answer (score 0):

Put an if condition to check if the value is 1, then use `yes` otherwise `no`.

```
$.getJSON('list.php', function(data) {
 $.each(data.classlists , function(i, f) {

         var tblRows = "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Info" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.messageName + "</td>" + "</tr>" +"<tr>" + "<td>" + "Link" + "</td>" +"<td><a target='_blank' href='"+link+"'>"+"Get INFO"+"</a></td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Teacher" + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.date + "</td>" + "</tr>" + "<tr>" + "<td>" + "Is Live Now" + "</td>" + "<td>" + (f.liveClassStatus === 1 ? 'Yes' : 'No') + "</td>" + "</tr>"  ;
```

Comment: please change your answer  in my question  because a minor mistake can throw my out of the world

Comment: Edited the answer. I hope 0 and 1 is coming as Number

Comment: Can you verify if 0 and 1 are coming as Number or string? If these are string, please replace with `(f.liveClassStatus === '1' ? 'Yes' : 'No')`

Comment: @Sachin - *please change your answer in my question* - that is not how this site works. If Nikhil edited your question with the correct answer then your question would no longer be the question you asked... it would be the fixed version. That would be confusing to anybody else who read it

Comment: Thanks sir now it working now. if we have do do more operation with 2, 3 4 ... then how can we do

Comment: You can create a function that will receive `f.liveClassStatus` as an argument and return the desired value. Also, please read and try to implement what @freefaller has told.